# Java: BufferedReader not printing out File content on TXT file

Tags: java, serialization, bufferedreader

I'm having issues with BufferedReader reading out the content of a txt file within a folder which is called via a method `showEditFile()` using an array with input of the user from method `pideNumero.preguntaUno();` which takes an int to iterate through the array positions  :

Array that loops through the Folder "Archivos".

```
    public static String[] testFiles() {

        String endPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String separator = File.separator;
        String folderPath = endPath + separator + "Archivos";

        File carpeta = new File(folderPath);

        String[] lista = carpeta.list();

        return lista;

    }
```

Method which would read the first line of the content which should be **Hellowwwww**:

```
 public static void showEditFile() throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Por Favor, elige un archivo con su numero para mostrar su contenido ");
        System.out.println("Los archivos dentro la carpeta Archivos son: ");
        Menu.listFiles.nomFiles();

        String[] archivos = Menu.listFiles.testFiles();

        int menu = Menu.pideNumero.preguntaUno();

        File document = new File(archivos[menu - 1]);

        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(document);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            line = br.readLine();

            System.out.println(line);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found." + document.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read file: " + document.toString());
        }
    }
```

I tried to check in Debug mode an see that on line `FileReader fr = new FileReader(document);` it would jump straight into the FileNotFoundException with the FilePath == **null** which I think comes the problem from.

It seems it doesn't know the path after "Archivos"

Path:
Root\Archivos\kiki.txt

**I've been stuck on this for a full day now can someone please help!**

Comment: The stack trace tells you where the problem is. Post it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`carpeta.list()` does not give fully qualified path. It only gives you file name. So next call `new File(archivos[menu - 1])` will fail. In `new File(archivos[menu - 1])` you will need to provide full and then you will not get Exception.  Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list()

Comment: Thank @Jags for this information! But how would I be able to store the "path" in the array so Java knows where to look more than just a name?

Comment: Also I understand it won´t fetch the path of that file with a list but what can I use inorder to do so. The program basically just needs to fetch the files and show them to the user. User give in a int input so it select one of those files. Once done it then need to read the content of the chosen file. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @Jags I figured the issue out. Solution below:

In my array I was returning a String[] which saves basically strings... So when I try to call it from my other method to read out the content it would show me the name of the file (which is a string but wouldn't have a file path assigned to it because it's just a string).

Changes I made here:

```
public static File[] testFiles() {

        String endPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String separator = File.separator;
        String folderPath = endPath + separator + "Archivos";

        File carpeta = new File(folderPath);
        // here as you can see i used the listFiles() method to list all the files and 
        // and save them into the File[] array
        File[] lista = carpeta.listFiles();   

        return lista;

    }
```

Now when calling the method in my other method showEditFiles() :

```
public static void showEditFile() throws IOException {

        System.out.println("Por Favor, elige un archivo con su numero para mostrar su contenido ");
        System.out.println("Los archivos dentro la carpeta Archivos son: ");
        Menu.listFiles.nomFiles();

        File[] archivos = Menu.listFiles.testFiles();

        int menu = Menu.pideNumero.preguntaUno();

        File document = new File(archivos[menu - 1]);

        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(document);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            line = br.readLine();

            System.out.println(line);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found." + document.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read file: " + document.toString());
        }
    }
```

Now it prints out the first line of the file (which in this case was hellow).

Comment: Glad that it worked. A minor suggestion. ```File document = new File(archivos[menu - 1]);``` -- here you don't need ```new File```. Your array already gives you File